In Spring Boot, does a @RequestParam binding error get caught by the CustomErrorController?
Skill Techs are Spring Boot, Thymeleaf.
I don't want to see Whitelabel page design.
I've created a CustomErrorController by inheriting from ErrorController to return my desired error pages.
public class CustomizedErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
        return "error/404";
    }
}

So, If some url doesn't exist or something wrong, I can show my custom html.
However, I encountered an issue where the whitelabel page appears again when providing an invalid query string value to a specific URL, despite having created a controller like the one below. I intended to use an enum to allow an ArgumentResolver to convert it into an object.
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl userDetails,
                       @RequestParam(required = false, name = "sort") TodoSort sort,
                       Model model) {
        Long id = userDetails.getUser().getId();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        List<TodoListDto> todoList = todoService.getTodoListByUserIdAndLocalDateAndSort(id, date, sort);
        model.addAttribute("todoList", todoList);

        return "user/home";
    }

I expected, when sort value is not subtable, ErrorController work!!
But, Just show whitelabel page...
So, my question is..
why does the ErrorController work when accessing a non-existing URL, but not when the query string format is incorrect? (I understand that to solve this issue, I should use @ControllerAdvice, but I'm curious about the reason behind this.)
I'm also curious whether it's appropriate to receive query string values using an enum like that.
Thank you!!!
test changing url, query String, etc..
